# Referring to global symbols

Tags: common-lisp

I want to create a source file in which most of the functions there defined, are local to that source file. It's the same purpose that would be served in C by marking the functions `static`; in C++ one could also surround them with `namespace { ... }`. I get the impression in Lisp, the package system is the appropriate tool. However, my attempts so far are not working.

This is what I currently have, but SBCL rejects it with the claim that `global-fun` is undefined. Explicitly referring to it as `cl-user:global-fun`, produces similar results. What should I be doing?

```
(defun global-fun ()
  (format t "global~%"))

(defpackage :local-package
  (:use :common-lisp)
  (:use :cl-user))
(in-package :local-package)

(defun local-fun ()
  (global-fun)
  (format t "local~%"))
```

Comment: Note that one usually does not want to *use* CL-USER, since it is undefined if it actually exports something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there. You might use Slime's autocompletion to find out.

Either export `global-fun`, or access it with a *double* colon: `(cl-user::global-fun)`.

With another `global-package`:

```
(defpackage :global-package
 (:use :common-lisp) ;; <-- can be :cl
 ;; (:use :cl-user) <-- not necessary
 (:export :global-fun))

 (in-package :global-package)

(defun global-fun () …)

(defpackage :local-package
  (:use :cl
        :global-defun)) ;; <-- one ":use" is possible
(in-package :local-package)

; etc
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some misconceptions here.

There is no such thing as a “global function” in Common Lisp.  The thing you defined first in your file, `global-fun` is in *some* package, most likely the `cl-user` package.

There is also no direct correspondence between packages and files.  You can define things for different packages in a single file, and you can define things for a single package in multiple files.  To make things unambiguous and easy to read, there is a very sensible convention to always start a source file with an `in-package` form (in some styles preceded by a `defpackage` form), and to never put another `in-package` somewhere later in the file.

When you write a symbol without package, e. g. `somefun` or `myarray`, it is interned (i. e. a sort of idempotent registration) into the current package (see below what that is).  This is independent from whether you currently define something or refer to it, because it is done by the *reader* when reading your source code forms.  In both of the following forms, the symbol named `foo` is interned into the current package (and both result in the identical symbol to be used):

```
(defun foo ()
  …)

(foo)
```

In order to refer to a symbol from a different package, you need to put the package name as a prefix with `::` as separator, as in `my-package::foo`, but this is usually a code smell because…

… you should export any symbols that a user of your package is intended to use, from your package definition:

```
(defpackage my-package
  (:use common-lisp)
  (:export foo))
```

You can refer to *exported* symbols from another package with a single colon as separator, as in `my-package:foo`, and this is good style.

Now, the *current package* is just the value of the variable `*package*`.  If you look at it from the point of view of a REPL session, this is the argument of the most recent `in-package` call.  In the context of whole file compilation, it is the value of the lexically closest preceding `in-package` form.  In the context of single-form compilation in a file, the IDE will (in any case I have seen) look for that preceding `in-package` form even if it is not evaluated explicitly.  In a pristine Lisp image, the starting package is `common-lisp-user`, which has a nickname `cl-user`.